# JavaFX 8 3D animation

Tags: java, animation, javafx, 3d

I am making a little JavaFX 8 project. I need some advices how to do the animation correctly. Something about the project. It's a program which animates the flow of a charged particle through magnetic field. All the needed values are taken from GUI where user puts them into textFields. After button click we are transfered to 3D scene where my point is shown as **Sphere**, all values are set up. And the field line is printed in it's directory.

The question is how to do the propper animation. I was trying to work with my Sphere X Y Z coordinates, but couldn't find any way to set those. The motion in **Z** plane should be linear with the same speed. And motion in **XY** planees should be circular. Can I do it with **Path Transition**?

My vision is to create the tick animation which draws the Spheres through the path. Whith a further tick the next sphere will be drew with new coordinates calculated by translation vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this possible using a `PathTransition`? No, paths are 2 dimensional in javafx, but you need a 3D movement.

Note that sphere coordinates not a good coordinate system to discribe such a movement either, since the calculation of the angles is a bit complex.

A coordinate system better suited would be **cylinder** coordinates.

You could use several transforms and animate those using a `Timeline` animation to achieve this kind of movement though:

```
private static void animateSphere(Sphere sphere) {
    Rotate rot = new Rotate();
    Translate radiusTranslate = new Translate(50, 0, 0);
    Translate zMovement = new Translate();

    sphere.getTransforms().setAll(zMovement, rot, radiusTranslate);
    Timeline tl = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                         new KeyValue(zMovement.zProperty(), 0d),
                         new KeyValue(rot.angleProperty(), 0d)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(4),
                         new KeyValue(zMovement.zProperty(), 900d, Interpolator.LINEAR),
                         new KeyValue(rot.angleProperty(), 720, Interpolator.LINEAR))
    );
    tl.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    tl.play();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Sphere sphere = new Sphere(30);

    Pane root = new Pane(sphere);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, true);
    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    camera.setTranslateZ(-10);
    camera.setTranslateX(-500);
    camera.setTranslateY(-200);
    camera.setRotationAxis(new Point3D(0, 1, 0));
    camera.setRotate(45);
    scene.setCamera(camera);

    animateSphere(sphere);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Your movement is a spiral movement and therefore the following combination of transformations will move the `Sphere` appropritately:

1. translate by radius (z component 0)
2. rotate to appropriate angle
3. translate in z direction

**Note:** Transforms are applied in reverse order in which they occur in the `transforms` list.

---

Alternatively you could write a helper that can be used with cylinder coordinate parameters and write the appropriate `x`, `y` and `z` values:

```
public class CylinderCoordinateAdapter {

    private final DoubleProperty theta = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private final DoubleProperty radius = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private final DoubleProperty h = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    private static final Point3D DEFAULT_AXIS = new Point3D(0, 0, 1);
    private Point3D axis2;
    private Point3D axis3;

    private final ObjectProperty<Point3D> axis = new SimpleObjectProperty<Point3D>() {

        @Override
        public void set(Point3D newValue) {
            newValue = (newValue == null || newValue.equals(Point3D.ZERO)) ? DEFAULT_AXIS : newValue.normalize();

            // find first value ortogonal to axis with z = 0
            axis2 = newValue.getX() == 0 && newValue.getY() == 0 ? new Point3D(1, 0, 0) : new Point3D(-newValue.getY(), newValue.getX(), 0).normalize();

            // find axis ortogonal to the other 2
            axis3 = newValue.crossProduct(axis2);
            super.set(newValue);
        }
    };

    public CylinderCoordinateAdapter(WritableValue<Number> x, WritableValue<Number> y, WritableValue<Number> z) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(x);
        Objects.requireNonNull(y);
        Objects.requireNonNull(z);
        axis.set(DEFAULT_AXIS);
        InvalidationListener listener = o -> {
            Point3D ax = axis.get();
            double h = getH();
            double theta = getTheta();
            double r = getRadius();

            Point3D endPoint = ax.multiply(h).add(axis2.multiply(Math.cos(theta) * r)).add(axis3.multiply(Math.sin(theta) * r));

            x.setValue(endPoint.getX());
            y.setValue(endPoint.getY());
            z.setValue(endPoint.getZ());
        };
        theta.addListener(listener);
        radius.addListener(listener);
        h.addListener(listener);
        axis.addListener(listener);

        listener.invalidated(null);
    }

    public final Point3D getAxis() {
        return this.axis.get();
    }

    public final void setAxis(Point3D value) {
        this.axis.set(value);
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<Point3D> axisProperty() {
        return this.axis;
    }

    public final double getH() {
        return this.h.get();
    }

    public final void setH(double value) {
        this.h.set(value);
    }

    public final DoubleProperty hProperty() {
        return this.h;
    }

    public final double getRadius() {
        return this.radius.get();
    }

    public final void setRadius(double value) {
        this.radius.set(value);
    }

    public final DoubleProperty radiusProperty() {
        return this.radius;
    }

    public final double getTheta() {
        return this.theta.get();
    }

    public final void setTheta(double value) {
        this.theta.set(value);
    }

    public final DoubleProperty thetaProperty() {
        return this.theta;
    }

}
```

```
private static void animateSphere(Sphere sphere) {
     CylinderCoordinateAdapter adapter = new CylinderCoordinateAdapter(
            sphere.translateXProperty(),
            sphere.translateYProperty(),
            sphere.translateZProperty());

    adapter.setRadius(50);

    Timeline tl = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                         new KeyValue(adapter.hProperty(), 0d),
                         new KeyValue(adapter.thetaProperty(), 0d)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(4),
                         new KeyValue(adapter.hProperty(), 900d, Interpolator.LINEAR),
                         new KeyValue(adapter.thetaProperty(), Math.PI * 4, Interpolator.LINEAR))
    );
    tl.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    tl.play();
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much! Will You be here for my further questions?

Comment: @LucasPG If it's a question about this answer, just write a comment. If it's a new question: I usually answer a few questions a day. If you write a question, it's written well enough, interesting, has no answer of sufficient quality and I know the answer, I'll probably post it... However there are also other quite competent users around who could answer your questions...

Comment: Hello. In my application the user puts all neded values. I have counted the radius of circular movement, also I have velocity on XY plane and velocity through Z axis. How Can I put all those 3 values to Your  animateSphere function to make the movement compatible with user values?

Comment: @LucasPG The transforms are applied in decreasing index order. The first one translates the sphere away from the origin, which means you need to replace the `50` by the radius. The next transformation is a rotation to move the node to the correct angle in the x/y pane. The angular velocity can be calculated using `360 * V_xy /  (2 * PI*r)`. The last transform moves the sphere in z direction.The last 2 values are animated by interpolation between given values for 2 frames. Given the values mentioned it shouldn't be too hard to come up with a suitable timespan and calculate the vals at start&end

Comment: I already have all values calucated. I changed 50 to my Radius, 900d to my Vz and 720 to Vxy. Is it correct way of thinking?

Comment: @LucasPG you also need to take into account the time between the `KeyFrame`s (4 seconds in this case). In this case you calculate the positions, i.e. replace `900d` with `Vz * 4` and the angle needs to be modified by `360` per full turn. In one turn a distance of `2 * Pi * R` is covered which means you need to replace `720` by `Vxy * 720 / (Pi * R)`

Comment: Thank You so much @fabian, it is working wery well. I got last question how can I extend time of the animoation? Thank You again.

Comment: @LucasPG Replace `Duration.seconds(4)` in the second `KeyFrame`. Keep in mind you also need to adjust the end values in the same frame accordingly...